# i keep getting this Undefined index: fname AND Notice: Undefined index: lname

Tags: html

*this is the php code and the one below is the HTML file. i keep getting the
 unidentified index error and i dont know why. please help!*

```
$firstname = $_POST["fname"];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(fname,lname)
VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname')";

         <form action="connect.php" method="post">
            First name: <input type="password" name="fname">
            Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up!" id="btnsignup" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **isset()** function to evaluate if the key is set.

example:

```
$firstname = isset($_POST["fname"]) ? $_POST["fname"] : '';
$lastname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
```

Comment: It fixed my problem but still fname would not be stored in the database. dont know why

Comment: the problem might be with your query. Try it as a one line like this: `$sql = "INSERT INTO user(fname,lname) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname')";`